# What is the Japanese Onomatopoeia for the sound a chainsaw makes?

Tags: english-to-japanese, onomatopoeia, sound-symbolism

From what I can tell, chainsaws make a sound like buzzing or rustling, etc. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find Japanese onomatopoeia from that sound. I wanted to look specifically for the chainsaw sound effect depicted in the manga, Chainsaw Man. Apart from that, it doesn't matter either.

Comment: Maybe this [chiebukuro post](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1463840004) will help? I feel like manga onomatopoeia is pretty liberally used though, and a lot of authors just come up with certain sounds when its convenient.

Comment: So why don't you check the "Chainsaw Man" to see what the author used?

Answer (score 8):

Basically, for very common sounds there is less variance in what onomatopoeia is used, but when it comes to uncommon sounds, there is a lot more diversity.

IMO Chainsaw is a relatively uncommon sound, so it's a bit up for grabs. I'd describe it as something like ブィーン　(an established onomatopoeia for electrical tools like drills).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it's late coming, and it may just be me, but wouldn't it be "girigiri" the sound of grinding? I believe Giriko from Soul Eater was named based on such due to being a chainsaw.

Comment: That's kind of funny, ''guiri'' (pronounced ''giri'') means ''foreigner'' in Spain.